# How to install proprietary drivers for Radeon HD 8570A/8570M on Fedora 21?

Tags: fedora, software-installation, drivers, ati, proprietary-drivers

Well i think i can't be more clear. I've tried this guide:

http://ilevex.eu/post/106904892091/how-to-use-fglrx-amd-catalyst-on-fedora-21

I've tried to just download the amd driver from support.amd.com and take all possible options: generate a distro package and install directly.

The problem is always the same:

**No supported adapters detected**

Here is my lspci:

```
bash-4.3$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] (rev ff)
08:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

As you can see, the Display Controller is:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun PRO [Radeon HD 8570A/8570M] (rev ff)
```

And lshw show this:

```
id:         generic
description:    Unassigned class
product:    Illegal Vendor ID
vendor:     Illegal Vendor ID
physical id:    0
bus info:   pci@0000:01:00.0
version:    ff
width:  32 bits
clock:  66MHz
capabilities:   bus_master vga_palette cap_list rom
configuration:  
driver  =   radeon
latency =   255
maxlatency  =   255
mingnt  =   255
resources:  
irq :   27
memory  :   b0000000-b7ffffff
memory  :   b8000000-b803ffff
ioport  :   4000(size=256)
memory  :   b8040000-b805ffff
```

Comment: Very weird! Illegal vendor & product IDs. That makes me believe that either your VGA is faulty or is miss placed into the PCI slot. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: In a laptop i think is not possible to have the pci slot misplaced. I will check.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize this was a laptop, sorry about that. I think replacing it under warranty might help.